# Measuring individual Voltage of the connected solar panel in series using I2C Protocol having GND in common as this get short circuited

Tags: arduino, power-electronics, i2c, solar-cell, electrical

I was stuck in a situation when i was measuring solar panels connected in series using I2C communication protocol. The common ground between the system makes the panel disconnected making a short loop.
As i am new to this community please help in this regard.
image of connection https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN6cb.jpg

i used voltage divider circuit with ATTiny85 as slave which measures individual panel voltage and communicates to master unit through I2C Protocol.

The problem is that the Ground of solar panel and the I2C are common which is making other panels out from the system.
I get reading of 12Volts in first panel and 0 Volts in other pannel.

What would be the best way to measure individual voltage and communicate to master unit.

i searched for operational and differential amplifier but not able to get it.
Kindly enlighten me in this aspect as i am new to electronics as my core is software development and product design.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We need a schematic. There is a button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Can the posted question be edited to upload any drawings

Comment: There is an 'edit' link under your post. There is an image button on the toolbar as well so that you can inline your images. I think there is a 2-image limit for new users but if you post them as .jpg someone with enough rep will fix them for you. (I didn't follow the link to see your image.)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem apparently comes down to getting low-bandwidth telemetry from multiple devices, each floating at various potentials.

Opto-isolators are good for getting data across arbitrary potentials.  However, IIC protocol is not well suited for this.  This is due to the bi-directional nature of the SDA line.

A better choice would be using a UART in each device.  You could gang all the optos that drive the individual RX lines together on your side.  In other words, you broadcast the same data to all devices.  You then also OR the outputs of the TX optos together.  Any device can drive the ganged TX line (your RX line) low, and it floats high when no opto is activated.

You use a higher level protocol where each device has a unique address, and responds only to a request to that address.  In other words, it is up to the protocol to ensure that only one device is trying to send at a time.  Your code on the master device then polls each of the slave devices in a endless loop.

Comment: in this case only data is transferred from slave devices to master when master request for address in a loop. There would be more than 50 panels connected in series.
Should i use IIC for this or go for UART as suggested .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need optical isolation or extra voltage regulators as long as you have a common ground between your Arduino and the solar panels.

If you optically isolate the second measurement system then you need a floating power supply, which needlessly introduces complexity.

You can use readily available I2C power/voltage monitors such as the TI [INA226](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina226.pdf) to achieve your task ...in fact you won't even need the ATTiny85's, they simply introduce yet another level of complexity you don't need. Your main Arduino can directly read from the INA226 boards without needing the ATTiny85's.

The INA226 is available very cheaply on Ebay, you can get boards for just $3 or so.

[image]

The INA226 is capable of measuring voltages up to 36 V, along with current so you could calculate the power you are getting from the panels.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4SJML.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your Arduino 3.3 V output can power the two INA226's easily.

The R1/R2 divider is just to ensure that even under high sun conditions you don't exceed the 36 V maximum of the INA226.